# BottomSheet not shown when use RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

I have the following code for bottom sheet

**xml file**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="@string/choose_option"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/recyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/titleTextview" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**View**

```
class AttributeOptionsBottomSheet(val viewModel: AttributeOptionsViewModel) : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun getTheme(): Int = R.style.AppBottomSheetDialogTheme

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_attributes, container, false)
        .also { view ->
            view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView).apply {
                context?.let {
                    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(Activity())
                    adapter = AttributeOptionsAdapter(viewModel)
                    viewModel.dismissView.observe({ lifecycle }) {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

**View Model**

```
class AttributeOptionsViewModel(attributeId: Int) : BaseViewModel() {

    val optionsDao: ExtraAttributeOptionDao by inject()
    var options : List<ExtraAttributeOptionEntity> = ArrayList<ExtraAttributeOptionEntity>()
    val dismissView = LiveEvent<Unit>()
    var optionSelected = LiveEvent<ExtraAttributeOptionEntity>()

    init {
        getOptions(attributeId)
    }

    fun getOptionName(position: Int): String {
        return options[position].name
    }

    fun setSelectedOption(position: Int) {
        options[position].apply {
            optionSelected.postValue(this)
            dismissView.postValue(Unit)
        }
    }

    fun getOptions(attributeId: Int) {
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            options = optionsDao.getExtraAttributeOptionsBuAttributeId(attributeId)
        }
    }
}
```

my problem is the bottom sheet is shown when there is small number of items, and it does not show with large number of items, the screen only dimmed and no thing happen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since i have not use it before i'm not sure that is the only solution.

Change your `RecyclerView` height to `wrap_content`

And add the next lines to your `TextView`

```
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
```

Or remove `bottom constraint` from `TextView` and add the same `bias` to `RecyclerView`

It has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

A little explanation on why @Merov solution works ( Btw thank you so much @Merov for saving the day).

- Inside a bottomsheet try to have fixed size or wrap content only. Setting to 0dp (match constraints) or match parents will not work. The height needs to be driven from children and not other way round.
- Setting the bias to 0 aligns the RV to top which will be center aligned otherwise
- Setting chain style to packed ensures that there are no gaps and all the items are packed one after another

Wanted to share this as I don't have enough credits to comment on answer. Hopefully this helps someone.